# Context menu on the left click

Tags: javascript, onclick, contextmenu, webix

I have a list with the context menu. Obviously, it appears on the right click by default. 
But how can I set the context menu to a left click?

```
webix.ui({
  rows:[
    { view:"list", id:"list", onContext:{},  data:[
      {value:"First"},
      {value:"Second"},
      {value:"Third"},
      {value:"Fourth"},
    ]},    
  ]
});

webix.ui({
  view:"contextmenu",
  id:"cmenu",
  data:["Like", "Dislike", "Report"],
}).attachTo($$('list'));
```

Here's a [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/6b26fb5f).

I've tried to use `onClick` event, but no luck

```
$$("list").attachEvent("onClick", function(id, context){    
    $$("cmenu").show(context);    
  });
```

Was I wrong somewhere? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the click event with [`onItemClick`](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.list_onitemclick_event.html):

```
$$('list').attachEvent("onItemClick", function(id, e, node){
    $$('cmenu').show(node);
});
```

Meaning when you click a list item, show the contex menu on the clicked item.

[**Snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/ba0c7eb3)

Comment: Thanks, got it! One more thing - is it possible to remove the same action from the right-click?

Comment: @Nathan You can remove the `.attachTo($$('list'));`.